# Bayes' estimate of mean parameter for normal data. how to get joint distribution?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, parameter-estimation

Let $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ be random samples of a normal r.v. X with unknown mean $\mu$ and variance 1.  Assume that $\mu$ is itself to be a normal rv with mean 0 and variance 1.  Find the Bayes estimator of $\mu$ (no problem here)

---

I'm given the **prior** distribution:

$$f(\mu) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\mu^2/2}\tag{1}$$

And I'm given the **apriori** distribution:

$$f(x_1,\cdots, x_n~ \mid~ \mu) = \Big(\frac{1}{2\pi}\Big)^{n/2} \exp\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2\Big]\tag{2}$$

They tell me to find the **joint** between the data $x_i$ and the parameter $\mu$, that is:

$$f(x_1, \cdots, x_n, \mu) = f(x_1, \cdots, f_n ~\mid~ \mu)~f(\mu)\tag{3}$$

I substitute (1) and (2) into (3) and I get:

$$f(x_1, \cdots, x_n , \mu) = \Big(\frac{1}{2\pi}\Big)^{n/2} \exp\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2\Big]\Big[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\mu^2/2}\Big]$$

After some algebra I get:

$$f(x_1, \cdots, x_n , \mu) = \frac{\exp\Big[-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{2} \Big]}{(2\pi)^{(n+1)/2}} \exp\Big[-\frac{(n+1)}{2}\Big(\mu^2 - \frac{2\mu}{n+1}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i \Big) \Big]\tag{4}$$

Then I let:

$$C = \frac{\exp\Big[-\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{2} \Big]}{(2\pi)^{(n+1)/2}}$$

$$f(x_1, \cdots, x_n , \mu) = C \exp\Big[-\frac{(n+1)}{2}\Big(\mu^2 - \frac{2\mu}{n+1}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i \Big) \Big]\tag{5}$$

And indeed (5) matches what the workbook says that I should get at this step in the problem.  Now, for the step I get stuck on.  The workbook further manipulates (4) to get (5):

$$f(x_1, \cdots, x_n , \mu) \\~~= C \cdot \exp\Bigg[ \frac{1}{2(n+1)}\Big(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i\Big)^2\Bigg] \cdot\exp\Bigg[-\frac{(n+1)}{2}\Big(\mu-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i\Big)^2\Bigg]\tag{6}$$

My question is, how did they get from (5) to (6)?

Comment: You should probably not call (2) the *apriori* distribution, as it just the Latin for *prior* which is (1). You are using (2) as the *likelihood*.

Comment: (2) is called the likelihood function?  that's good to know...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability

Comment: Complete the square.